# Send local image file to api call

Tags: java, android, http

I'm new to android development and I'm working on an app that is supposed to send a local image file to a web service and get the response back.

I was able to send a URL of an image from general online sources through my code, and it worked.
But the requirement is to pass an image from the gallery via the API.

The Code I have set up is giving me an invalid URL error when I get the information for the image selected as below. How do I get around this to pass the image from the gallery?

The API allows for multipart/form-data too. I'm not sure how to extract the image data for it using the gallery data.

**I have commented the line of code in the JSON object accumulate which does not work.**

'''

```
        //setting uploaded image to view
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        //get url
        String URILOCATION = selectedImage.getPath();

        imageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try
        {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v3.0/Prediction/aaead50a-95cd-403c-a3c2-9b774399e43b/classify/iterations/Iteration6/url");
            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Prediction-key", predictionApiKey);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("url","https://i.ibb.co/XCnhQ2m/IMG20210503153531.jpg");
            //jsonObject.accumulate("url",URILOCATION);
            
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();


            // Request body
            StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(json);
            request.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null)
            {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
```

'''

Comment: `String URILOCATION = selectedImage.getPath();` That is no file system path. Now i do believe that you can send that string to the server. But have a look at its value! After that send  `URILOCATION = selectedImage.toString();` to see that it is a nice content scheme.

Comment: Thanks alot for your feed back! really appreciate. so i did try it out. but i think im at the same error still.

Comment: You are supposed to tell us the values of those two strings...